# How to delete every third element as a loop from an array?

Tags: java, arrays

Adding 6 numbers as 1,2,3,4,5,6
Need to remove values in loop with a difference of 2.

Desired Result : Removal of 3 in the first loop followed by 6 followed by 4 followed by 2 followed by 5 & at last by 1.

Here's my code:

```
while(array.length ! = 1) 
{ 

    for(int i =2; i<array.length; i=i+2) 
    { 
         array = ArrayUtils.remove(array, i); 
         System.out.println("Content of Array after removing an object : " 
            + Arrays.toString(array)); 
    }               
}
```

Getting result as

Content of Array after removing an object : [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]

Content of Array after removing an object : [1, 2, 4, 5]

Content of Array after removing an object : [1, 2, 5]

Content of Array after removing an object : [1, 2]

Please help

Comment: Please show us what you've got so far.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: modulo is your friend

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @NPE Shared d code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, once the array is down to two elements, you may receive a NullPointerException because you are trying to refer to an element with index '2' (because you set int i =2), but there are only two elements, and index '2' would refer to a nonexistent third element.

One way to do it would be adding an edge-case condition. For example, you could make an if statement for when the array size is less than or equal to three, and change which element it removes.

The problem here isn't a code issue but a logical issue.

Answer (score 0):

Providing a second example run would help me determine if this code works, but I have it doing what you want so far. I was roaming around for unanswered C# questions, so I apologize, but it's in C#, not Java. Sorry for the mess, but I only have a few minutes until my work day is over!

```
var myList = new List<int>() {
  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
};
var broken = 0;
var step = 2;

while (myList.Count > 0) {
  for (var i = step; i < myList.Count; i += step) {
    if (broken == 1) {
      myList.RemoveAt(i);
      myList.ForEach(x => Console.Write("{0} ", x));
      Console.Write("\n");
      step--;
      broken = 0;
      continue;
    }
    if (!(i + step >= myList.Count)) {
      myList.RemoveAt(i);
      myList.ForEach(x => Console.Write("{0} ", x));
      Console.Write("\n");
    } else {
      myList.RemoveAt(i);
      myList.ForEach(x => Console.Write("{0} ", x));
      Console.Write("\n");
      broken = 1;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Output is:

```
1 2 4 5 6
1 2 4 5
1 2 5
1 5
1
[list has no elements at this point]
```